# How to get rid of the exception "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine" in Win 7

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbconnection, oledbexception, oledbdataadapter

I am running an ASP.NET C# application on .NET 4.0 framework using VS2010 on a Win 7 machine.  Within my code I want to link Excel file with "DataTable" object. ie I want to access the data within Excel file and store it in DataTable object. So I used the following code snippet:

_

```
_connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\"" + excelFile + "\";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0; HDR=NO; IMEX=1'";
        }

DataTable table = new DataTable();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = new OleDbConnection(_connectionString);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = "select * from [NameOFExcelSheet$A1:D20]";  // Want to read the Excel sheet. The name of Excel sheet is "NameOfExcelSheet". Wan to read the celles in the range A1 and D20.

            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(table);  // EXCEPTION OCCURS IN THIS LINE.
```

I installed the exe available at the link http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?FamilyID=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=en

But still I am gettin the same exception msg while running my code. 
The exception that I am getting is **"The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"**

PLz help me with this.

THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Comment: ~39/56 unaccepted answers. You should spare a moment to go through and accept some more answers.

Comment: I would suggest, when asking about some exception provide details about it: type, message. It will helps - nobody have crystal ball.

Comment: Hi, the question text has the Exception in it. I have again edited my question and have included it in the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably on 64bit Windows and installed a 32bit driver. Either switch to 32bit compilation or source a 64bit driver.

Comment: Can you plz let me know 1) How to switch to 32bit compilation. OR 2) Provide a 64bit driver. Pardon if I sound silly. I am a fresher in this. Kindly let me know.

Comment: You need to add a new configuration in the "Configuration Manager" under the "build" menu in VS. This MSDN article explains how to go to x64. The steps are the same for x86. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185328.aspx

Comment: You're probably on the right track.  However, there is no 64-bit redistributable for that provider and he's using ASP.NET.  He has to enable a 32-bit application pool.

Comment: Ah. Missed the ASP.NET part of it. Well spotted @Hans

Comment: I changed it to 32 bit compilation mmode and it worked fine for me. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should try this (ensuring that you are in a x86 (32bits) machine ):

This download will install a set of components that can be used to facilitate transfer of data between 2007 Microsoft Office System files and non-Microsoft Office applications.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=en

Comment: Well but my app runs in 64 bit Win 7 machine. How shall I go about it.

Comment: Then you should switch to 32 bit compilation like @spender said

Im not sure where its, try:
"Properties of project>Compile>Advanced Compile > In the dropdown choose x86 (32 bits)"